# Pentaho Report Tabular Filas

Tags: report, pentaho

Estoy usando Pentaho Report Designer y necesito hacer un informe en el que algunas filas del informe llevan tabulación. Dentro de los datos del informe tengo uno que es "Nivel" que me indica el nivel de tabulación de ese campo. Me gustaría saber como poder darle un cierto padding dependiendo de ese campo "nivel" o si lo estoy enfocando correctamente.

Un ejemplo seria:

```
Balance
   Activo
      A Activo tal....
         1.1  lo que sea
      B Activo cual
         1.4
  Pasivo
      A Pasivo Tal...
```

Cada fila tiene un campo valor de tabulación que podría usar para hacer el informe.

Answer (score 0):

```
Si el campo lvl = 12 el padding 70 etc...
```

Estoy hay que hacerlo haciendo click sobre el campo al que queremos hacerle el padding, pinchando sobre el + y en la formula ponemos la condición que queramos.
Yo lo he hecho sobre el campo nombre, hago el padding al campo nombre dependiendo del valor del campo lvl. Espero que se haya entendido. :)

```
 =   IF( [lvl]=12; "70";      IF ([lvl] = 10; "60"; IF ([lvl] = 8; "50";   IF ([lvl] = 6; "40"; IF ([lvl] = 4; "30"; IF ([lvl] = 2; "20"))))))
```